# Finding the Dimension of a Matrix Polynomial: $W$ = { $p(B)$ : $p$ is a polynomial with real coefficients}

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W = \{ p(B) : p \text{ is a polynomial with real coefficients}\}$, where
$$B=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Which of the following possibilities presents the tightest bounds on the dimension $d$ of the vector space $W$?

1. $4 ≤ d ≤ 6$
2. $6 ≤ d ≤ 9$
3. $3 ≤ d ≤ 8$
4. $3 ≤ d ≤ 4$

Comment: Could you phrase your post as a question, and also tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I edited this post to turn it into a *question*.  I may edit it further to provide some motivation and/or context.

Answer (score 5):

First, check that $W$ is a subspace: If $p_1(B),p_2(B) \in W$, then $(p_1+p_2)(B) \in W$ and if $p(B)\in W$, then $(\lambda p)(B) \in W$.
The dimension of a subspace is the maximum number of linearly independent vectors (or on this case, matrices, which can also be viewed as vectors)

The [Cayley Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) tells us that the characteristic polynomial $\chi(x) = \det (xI -B)$ of $B$ satisfies $\chi(B) = 0$.

Since the characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $\chi(x)=x^3-1$, Cayley Hamilton gives (also by direct computation) $B^3 - I=0$, or $B^3 = I$. 
In particular, we have $B^k = B^{k \text{ mod } 3}$ and so any power of $B$ can be written as one of $I,B,B^2$, and hence if $p$ is a polynomial, we can write $p(B) = p_0I+p_1B+p_2 B^2$ for some $p_0,p_1,p_2$. That is, $I,B,B^2$ form a spanning set for $W$.

Hence $W \subset \operatorname{sp} \{I,B,B^2\}$, and we see that $d=\dim W \le 3$.

To see that $d=3$, we need to show that $I,B,B^2$ are linearly independent.

Note that $B^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Now suppose $\alpha_0 I+\alpha_1 B + \alpha_2 B^2 = 0$. Since $B_{11} = (B^2)_{11} = 0$, it follows that $\alpha_0 = 0$. Since $I_{31} = (B^2)_{31} = 0$, it follows that $\alpha_1 = 0$, and since $B^2 \neq 0$, it follows that $\alpha_2 =0$. Hence they are linearly independent and so 
$I,B,B^2$ form a basis for $W$, and so $d=3$.

Comment: I suspect the OP may not quite understand what it means that two matrices are linearly independent.

Comment: Then dimension of $W$ would be out of reach? (But, point taken, I will elaborate.)

Comment: That's what I would imagine.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Yes, thanks. Loose writing on my part. Will correct.

Answer (score 2):

$B$  represents a rotation by $2\pi/3$ about the axis $(1,1,1)^\top.$ we also claim that $$\{I, B, B^2\} \text{ is linearly independent. } $$ 
proof of the claim: suppose $$aI + bB + cB^2 = 0 $$ multiplying on the right by $(1,0,0)^\top$ gives $$a(1,0,0)^T + b(0,0,1)^\top+c(0,1,0)^\top = 0 \implies a = 0, b = 0, c = 0.$$ this proves the claim.  therefore a basis for $W$ is  $\{I, B, B^2\}$ and its dimension is $3.$

Comment: Nice answer, ***endorsed!***  But how do we know, as claimed, and as on your whole argument depends, that your first sentence holds?  (I already know the answer to this, but I think it would enhance your answer to include it.)  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis, thanks. you really don't need the geometrical interpretation of $B$ for the result to hold.  one can verify that $(1,1,1)$ is fixed by $B$ and  the angle between $u$ in the plane $x + y + z = 0$ and $Bu$ is $2\pi/3.$

Comment: I guess you' d do that by looking at $\langle b, Bu \rangle / ( \Vert u \Vert \Vert Bu \Vert)$?  Still, it would be nice to see it written up with your customary elegance!

Comment: @RobertLewis, being a little sarcastic there?

Comment: In fact, no.  I've read and respected many of your answers!  My complement is genuine!

Comment: I  can in fact be *quite* sarcastic, but I try to keep that skill in check on MSE!

Comment: @RobertLewis, sorry i misunderstood you. thanks again. i will write up a little more later. have a good day.

Comment: Looking forward to reading it!  Keep up the good work!  Have a good day yourself!

Comment: Thanks a lot...I understood but What about the upper bound.? Is dimension exactly 3.?

Comment: @SamChristopher, the dimension is exactly three. the set $\{I, B, B^2\}$ obviously spans $W$ and it is shown that it is linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat more ring-theoretic approach; though a bit long-winded, I believe it has certain advantages:  first, it does not depend in an essential way on the *specific* structure of the matrix $B$; any $B$ satisfying (4)-(7) below will give rise to the same conclusion; second, from this abstract viewpoint, it is easier to see how the question may be generalized to other matrices; third, it avoids a lot of explicit matrix computation, which I for one don't find the most enjoyable of mathematical activities.

Consider $\Bbb R[B]$, the $\Bbb R$-algebra of real polynomials in the matrix $B$; it is clearly a subalgebra of $M_3(\Bbb R)$, the full algebra of $3 \times 3$ matrices with coefficients in $\Bbb R$.  Furthermore, we have in the usual way a (pretty) natural homomorphism $\theta:\Bbb R[x] \to \Bbb R[B]$ defined by

$\theta(\sum_0^n c_i x^i) = \sum_0^n c_i B^i \in \Bbb R[B] \tag{1}$

for all $\sum_0^n c_i x^i \in \Bbb R[x]$, where $\Bbb R[x]$ is as usual the ring of polynomials in $x$ with real coefficients.  That $\theta$ is in fact an algebra, hence a ring, homomorphism is easy to see; so easy, in fact, that I shall omit the details of the verification; those interested in such details might find it helpful to consult Sheldon Axler's little book, *Linear Algebra Done Right*, where in the section of Chapter 5 titled "Polynomials Applied to Operators" he explains the whole stuck in less than two pages.  This book is familiar to many MSE users, Yours Truly included; I found my nearly brand new copy on a sidewalk here in Oakland, California, where people often leave useful items free for the taking.

These things being said, we return our attentions to the map $\theta$ itself.

It is clear that $\theta$ is surjective, for given $\sum_0^n c_i B^i \in \Bbb R[B]$, taking $\sum_0^n c_i x^i \in \Bbb R[x]$ yields (1).

We compute

$\ker \theta = \{ p(x) \in \Bbb R[x] \mid \theta(p(x)) = p(B) = 0 \}. \tag{2}$

In order to do this we will need to introduce several properties of the given matrix

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{3}$

we then have:

$B^3 = I; \tag{4}$

$(B - I)(B^2 + B + I) = 0; \tag{5}$

$B - I \ne 0; \tag{6}$

$B^2 + B + I \ne 0. \tag{7}$

(4) holds by direct calculation; (5) follows from (4) *via*

$(B - I)(B^2 + B + I) = B^3 - I = 0; \tag{8}$

(6) binds since it is equivalent to $B \ne I$, which is evident from inspection of $B$; (7) is again verified by direct computation, noting that

$B^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{9}$

thus

$B^2 + B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \ne -I. \tag{10}$

(4)-(7) are the only properties of $B$ we shall need; by their virtue, we may avoid further algebraic manipulation of the entries of $B$ *per se*, thus sparing ourselves the vicissitudes of extensive arithmetic.

We observe that

$(x^3 - 1) \subset \ker \theta, \tag{11}$

where $(x^3 - 1) $ is the principal ideal in $\Bbb R[x]$ generated by $x^3 - 1$; that is

$(x^3 -1) = \{ f(x)(x^3 - 1) \mid f(x) \in \Bbb R[x] \}; \tag{12}$

(11) follows from (4) and (12) since

$\theta(f(x)(x^3 -1)) = \theta(f(x)) \theta(x^3 - 1) = f(B)(B^3 - I) = 0. \tag{13}$

Having (11), we take things one step further and show that in fact

$\ker \theta = (x^3 - 1).  \tag{14}$

We recall that $\Bbb R$ being a field, $\Bbb R[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, hence a prinicpal ideal domain; thus

$\ker \theta = (k(x)) \tag{15}$

for some $k(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$; by (11),

$x^3 - 1 \in \ker \theta = (k(x)); \tag{16}$

thus

$x^3 - 1 = q(x) k(x) \tag{17}$

for some $q(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$; since

$\deg q(x) + \deg k(x) = \deg x^3 - 1 = 3, \tag{18}$

if follows that

$0 \le \deg k(x) \le 3; \tag{19}$

also, in $\Bbb R[x]$ we note that $x^3 - 1$ may be factored as:

$x^3 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1), \tag{20}$

with both $x - 1$ and $x^2 + x + 1$ irreducible in $\Bbb R[x]$; $x - 1$ is irreucible since is of degree one; on the other hand, if $x^2 + x + 1$ were reducible in $\Bbb R[x]$ we could write

$x^2 + x + 1 = (x - \alpha)(x - \beta) \tag{21}$

with $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R[x]$; but the zeros of $x^2 + x + 1$ are, by the quadratic formula

$\alpha, \beta = \dfrac{1}{2}(-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}) \notin \Bbb R; \tag{22}$

it follows that $x^2 + x + 1$ cannot expressed as the product of linear factors in $\Bbb R[x]$; hence it is irreducible; since as has been noted $\Bbb R[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, its irreducibles and primes coincide, implying that $x - 1$ and $x^2 + x + 1$ are both prime in $\Bbb R[x]$.

Turning again to (17), and using (20), we write

$(x -1)(x^2 + x + 1) = q(x)k(x); \tag{23}$

recalling once again that $\Bbb R[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, we invoke the standard result that unique factorization into primes/irreducibles holds in $\Bbb R[x]$;
applying this conclusion to (23) implies that there are *precisely four* possibilities for $k(x)$, in accord with whether or not none, one, or both of the primes $x - 1$, $x^2 + x + 1$ occurs as a divisor; they are:

$k(x) = 1; q(x) = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1) = x^3 - 1; \tag{24}$

$k(x) = x - 1; q(x) = x^2 + x + 1; \tag{25}$

$k(x) = x^2 + x + 1; q(x) = x - 1; \tag{26}$

and

$k(x) = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1) = x^3 - 1; q(x) = 1.  \tag{27}$

We systematically eliminate candidates (24)-(26):  $k(x) = 1$ implies $\ker \theta = (1) = \Bbb R[x]$ or $\theta = 0$, which contadicts (1); $k(x) = x - 1$ implies $B - I = \theta(x) - \theta(1) = \theta(x - 1) = 0$, in opposition to (6); likewise $k(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ yields $B^2 + B + I = 0$, prohibited by (7); we are left with $k(x) = x^3 - 1$, whence

$\ker \theta = (x^3 - 1).  \tag{28}$

By (28) and the fact that $\theta$ is an epimorphism, we see that

$ \tilde \theta: \Bbb R[x]/ \ker \theta \cong \Bbb R[B], \tag{29}$

where $\tilde \theta:\Bbb R[x]/ \ker \theta \to \Bbb R[B]$ is the homomorphism induced by $\theta$.  We have shown that the isomorphism $\tilde \theta$ referred to in (29) is an isomorphism of *algebras*, i.e., it isomorphically maps the both the ring and vector space structure of $\Bbb R[x] / \ker \theta$ to that of $\Bbb R[B]$.  That this is so follows from the facts that (i.)  $\theta$ itself, in addition to being a ring homomorphism, is also a linear map of $\Bbb R[x]$ onto $\Bbb R[B]$, and (ii.), $\ker \theta$ is a linear subspace of $\Bbb R[x]$:  for any $a \in \Bbb R$ and any $p(x) \in \ker \theta$, we easily see from (1) that

$\theta(ap(x)) = ap(B) = 0; \tag{30}$

thus $ap(x) \in \ker \theta$, and $\ker \theta$ is a claimed a (vector) subspace of $\Bbb R[x]$.  We thus conclude that the induced map $\tilde \theta$ of (29) is an *algebra isomorphism*, preserving both the ring *and* vector space structures of $\Bbb R[x] / \ker \theta$.  And from this we further conclude that the dimension of $\Bbb R[B]$ over $\Bbb R$ is equal to that of $\Bbb R[x]/\ker \theta$.

It thus remains to evaluate $\dim (\Bbb R[x] / \ker \theta)$ over $\Bbb R$; but this is easy:  from the Euclidean algorithm, we have that the quadratic polynomials $\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma$ form a complete set of coset representatives of $\Bbb R[x] / \ker \theta$, since for any $p(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$ we may write

$p(x) = q(x)(x^3 - 1) + r(x) \tag{31}$

for some *unique* $q(x), r(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$ with $r(x) = 0$ or $\deg r(x) < 3$; (31) may also be written

$p(x) - r(x) = q(x)(x^3 - 1) \in (x^3 - 1) = \ker \theta.  \tag{32}$

If we denote by $\overline{p(x)}$ the coset $p(x) + \ker \theta \in \Bbb R[x] / \ker \theta$, then according to (32),

$\overline{p(x)} = \overline{r(x)}, \tag{33}$

since

$\ker \theta = (x^3 - 1 ) = 0 \in \Bbb R[x] / \ker \theta \tag{34}$

is the additive identity, or zero element, of $\Bbb R[x] / \ker \theta$.

Also,

$\overline{r(x)} = \overline{\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma} = \alpha \bar x^2 + \beta \bar x + \gamma. \tag{35}$

From (33) and (35) we immmediatly conclude that $\dim \Bbb R[x] / \ker \theta$ it most $3$ over $\Bbb R$; since it is spanned by $\bar 1$, $\bar x$, $\bar x^2$; furthermore, these three elements of $\Bbb R[x] / \ker \theta$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb R$, since

$\alpha \bar x^2 + \beta \bar x + \gamma = 0 \in \Bbb R[x]/\ker \theta \tag{36}$

implies

$\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma \in \ker \theta = (x^3 - 1); \tag{37}$

however, the degree of every non-zero polynomial $f(x) = q(x)(x^3 - 1)$ in $(x^3 - 1)$ is *at least* $3$, since it has $x^3 - 1$ as a factor; thus we must have $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$ and $\bar 1$, $\bar x$, $\bar x^2$ are linearly independent in $\Bbb R[x] / \ker \theta$, whence $\dim \Bbb R[x]/\ker \theta = 3$ over $\Bbb R$; the same is thus true of $\Bbb R[B]$.