# How to find the dimension of the given vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $L=\{p(B)|\ p\ \text{is a polynomial with real coefficients}\},$ where $B =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 &0\\0 & 0&1\\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$ Then the dimension $\;d\;$ of the vector space $L$ satisfies

1. $ 4\leq d\leq 6$
2. $ 6\leq d\leq 9$
3. $ 3\leq d\leq 8$
4. $ 3\leq d\leq 4$.

   Since  $ B^3=I,$ we have $L=\{a+bB+cB^2\}.$ So 1 and 2 are wrong

How to proceed further, Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You're very close to being done.  Since you have $L$ written as ${aI+bB+cB^2}$, you have a finite spanning set.  Is this set now a basis?

Comment: You really almost answered the question yourself. When you know that $L=\{a+bB+cB^2\}$ can you find a basis of $L$?

Comment: I think $\{I,B,B^2\}$ forms a basis.

Comment: @yazhini That's it=)

Comment: @flawr But what is the correct option? Both 3 and 4?

Comment: Well since your basis consitst of 3 vectors, then $d=3$, so yes, 3 and 4 are correct!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the Dimension of a Matrix Polynomial: $W$ = { $p(B)$ : $p$ is a polynomial with real coefficients}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261913/finding-the-dimension-of-a-matrix-polynomial-w-pb-p-is-a-polynomi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know $x^3+1$  is a multiple of the minimal polynomial of $B$. It is easy to check no quadratic polynomial is  $0$ at $B$. Hence:
$$L\simeq \mathbf R[x]/(x^3+1),$$
which has dimension $3$ over $\mathbf R$. A basis of the latter is $(\bar 1, \bar x, \bar x^2)$, hence a basis of $L$ is $\,(I, B, B^2)$.